# How to access attribute value when child is text node using Nori

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I tried this:

```
xml_parser = Nori.new
xml_parser.parse "<FareReference ResBookDesigCode='Q'>Value</FareReference>"
```

And the result is:

```
{"FareReference"=>"Value"}
```

I wanted to retrieve the `ResBookDesigCode` value also.

Comment: Considering that [Nori](https://github.com/savonrb/nori) hasn't had any development in 4+ years, I'd say you should find a different candidate. Personally I recommend Nokogiri but YMMV. You might like Ox, especially its ability to [parse XML into a hash](https://github.com/ohler55/ox#parsing-xml-into-a-hash-fast).

Answer (score 0):

Nokogiri is my recommended tool since Nori doesn't appear it's being actively supported.

```rb
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML("<FareReference ResBookDesigCode='Q'>Value</FareReference>")
```

`doc` now contains the DOM for the XML.

We can access the content for the `FareReference` node easily, along with its parameters:

```rb
doc.at('FareReference').text # => "Value"
doc.at('FareReference')['ResBookDesigCode'] # => "Q"
```

[`at`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Searchable.html#at-instance_method) basically means find the first node containing that selector. The documentation and tutorials describe the sibling methods.